# Set threads affinity on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp, cpu, affinity

I have a CPU-intensive code (it uses [Semi-Global Stereo Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/calib3d/StereoSGBM.html)) that runs multicore, since I've enabled `WITH_OPENMP` flag when compiling OpenCV for Visual Studio 2013 x64.

However, this code runs on *all* of my 8 logical cores (I have a 4-cores CPU with HyperThreading). I want to restrict the used cores to just Core #1, #3, #5, #7. I know that, with some OpenMP implementations, one can set the affinity at compile-time using environment variables (example for [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-thread-affinity-control), [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html)).

So how can I configure OpenCV to use threads with this affinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft compiler can use only [openmp 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/openmp-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017) and don't support an affinity mask - only [OMP_NUM_THREADS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-environment-variables?view=vs-2017).